# Trying to return a boolean value from a function

Tags: python, if-statement, return, boolean

I am trying to program a simple text based game. In order to do this, I am having the user go to three separate rooms to complete a task and receive a piece. In order to do this, I have a value set as `False` then, upon completion of the room, I have a `return` statement used to change the Boolean value to `True`. When all three room functions return a `True`, then I set that to open a function that progresses the game. As of know, however, the return does not take place, and thus the Boolean values remain unchanged.
Here is an example of one door function:

```
def door1(incomp1):
    if incomp1 == False:
        print 'You enter door 1 and find a hideous internet troll.'
        print "The troll says, 'LOOK AT THIS LOSER'"
        options = ["YOU'RE THE LOSER", "I don't care." , "YOUR MOM IS FAT"]
        options2 = [1,2,3]
        for x in options:
            print "\t :> %s" % x
        choice1 = raw_input("What is your response? :>")
        if ('loser' in choice1) or ('fat' in choice1):
            print "You are sucked into the troll's behaviour and are driven insane"
            print "After three days of insanity, you starve to death"
            dead()
        elif 'care' in choice1:
            print 'The troll cannot feed off of your anger.'
            print 'The troll starves and you recover one piece of the lever from his stomach.'
            change()
            entrywayopen()
            return incomp1 == True
        else:
            unknown()
            change()
            door1(incomp1)
    elif incomp1 == True:
        print 'You already recovered the piece from room 1.'
        entrywayopen()
```

So, I have `incomp1` already at a value of `False` when the function is called. The user must get the correct answer, in this case the `elif` statement. At the end, I have it to `return incomp1 == True`. Yet, the value remains unchanged. My endgame in this room strategy is to return a value of `True` for the statement `if  door1(incomp1)  and door2(incomp2) and door3(incomp3):`. What is causing the Boolean change in value to not be returned?

Comment: Did you try running a debugger on this?

Comment: try printing the value of the variable you are passing to this function before the function is called. also how are you storing the values once a room is complete?

Answer (score 1):

A little about Python boolean expressions:

- every python expression can be evaluated as a boolean
- `None`, `False`, `0`, `0.0`, empty strings, lists, tuples and dictionaries are `False`; most others objects are `True`
- that means: instead of `x == True` you can usually just write `x`, in your case: `if incomp1:`

If you are executing a function and it finishes without hitting a `return`, a `None` will be returned implicitly. If you do a boolean comparison on it, it will evaluate as `False`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace "return incomp1 == True" with just "return True". Then call the door1 function like this "incomp1 = door1(incomp1)". 
This will change the value of incomp1 to the value returned by the function "True".

You can also replace "elif incomp1 == True:" with a simple "else".

You might also consider adding a .lower() to choice1 = raw_input("What is your response? :>"). This will make it so if the player uses a capital letter in the input it will still function as desired.

```
def door1(incomp1):
    if incomp1 == False:
        print 'You enter door 1 and find a hideous internet troll.'
        print "The troll says, 'LOOK AT THIS LOSER'"
        options = ["YOU'RE THE LOSER", "I don't care." , "YOUR MOM IS FAT"]
        options2 = [1,2,3]
        for x in options:
            print "\t :> %s" % x
        #choice1 = raw_input("What is your response? :>")
        choice1 = raw_input("What is your response? :>").lower()
        if ('loser' in choice1) or ('fat' in choice1):
            print "You are sucked into the troll's behaviour and are driven insane"
            print "After three days of insanity, you starve to death"
            dead()
        elif 'care' in choice1:
            print 'The troll cannot feed off of your anger.'
            print 'The troll starves and you recover one piece of the lever from his stomach.'
            change()
            entrywayopen()
            return True
        else:
            unknown()
            change()
            door1(incomp1)
    #elif incomp1 == True:
    else:
        print 'You already recovered the piece from room 1.'
        entrywayopen()

incomp1 = door1(incomp1)
```